# Java API to control Rancher 2

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, rancher

at the moment I am using Rancher 2 (v2.0.8) to configure my containers.
Is there any recommened library for java , that supports rancher 2? (i only found older projects for Rancher 1).
It would be great to have a java api instead of using ony plain rest-services.
Thanks alot in advance

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently only Python and Go clients are available. I am not aware of any Java clients. (PRs welcome :))

For sample usage of the clients checkout these repositories:

- https://github.com/rancher/validation-tests/tree/master/tests/v3_validation (Python)
- https://github.com/leodotcloud/test-network-policy (Go)

When you are working Rancher 2.0 API using these clients, you need to be aware of using different clients: management, cluster and project.